# How to finish the program and continue to upload file in the background in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

noob here, have been looking around for this question and couldn't find the answers.

pseudo code example to illustrate my question:

```
# In test.py    

# doing upload things and taking 15 min
async def upload_big_things_to_db(file_path):    
    await upload(file_path)
    ...

def main():
    
    # Do something in main
    file_path = figure_out_file_path()

    # I don't want to wait for this, how do I make this call to another process and finish this 
    await upload_big_things_to_db(file_path)
    return None
```

python test.py

It should take a couple of seconds and have another process running in the background and doing `upload_big_things_to_db`

I was reading through asyncio, but couldn't find what I wanted.
Can anyone help plz?